# Xaml binding not working with Application.Current

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

So I have two global properties Username and CurrentView defined in App.xaml.cs and im binding them in my Views.

**App.xaml.cs**

```
 public partial class App : Application, INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
    public static object username;

    public object Username { get { return username; } set { username = value; } }

    public static Object currentView = new LoginView();

    public object CurrentView
    {
        get { return currentView; }
        set { currentView = value; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

And im binding both of them in different Views.
**MainView.xaml**

```
    <Page  Content="{Binding CurrentView, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}">          
    </Page>
```

**LoginView.xaml**

```
    <TextBox  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="165" Margin="218,159,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Username, Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
```

The binding in MainView is working perfectly fine. It is showing me LoginView which I have initialized CurrentView to in app.xaml.cs and it changes when the source is changed.

However username is not updating which is binded with the textbox in LoginView.
Cant seem to figure out the problem. It should update as Iv set the UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged.

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The Text property of the `TextBox` is of type `string` but your `Username` property is an `object`

Consider changing the `Username` property to string rather than object. If you need it to be an object, you need to have a converter in order for the binding to properly set it.

Also, looking at your binding I notice you have it set up as OneWay. Change that to TwoWay to ensure the Binding updates both ways from Source and Target.

Comment: Iv changed it to string. Still no luck :(

 public static string username;
        public string Username { get { return username; } set { username = value; } }

Comment: Iv tried it on all modes. still nothing. But ill keep it to TwoWay